# Android Facebook SDK 4.0 login with LoginManager

Tags: android, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to migrate login code of an old application from SDK 3.0 to SDK 4.0.
I have implemented the Login using the `LoginManager`, as I have custom Login buttons.

The problem is that I get no response from the Facebook API. No success, no error, no exception thrown whatsoever. The code is as below:

```
    //global refs
    //callbacks
    private CallbackManager mCallbackManager;
    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mFacebookCallback;

    private List<String> mPermissions = Arrays.asList("email");
    private LoginManager mLoginMgr;
    private Activity mActivity;

    //........

    //code is inside method
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

    //perhaps a bit excessive
    FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.GRAPH_API_DEBUG_INFO);
    FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.DEVELOPER_ERRORS);
    FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    FacebookSdk.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_RAW_RESPONSES);
    FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(mActivity.getString(R.string.sample_fb_id));

    //init callbacks
    mFacebookCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Log.v("LoginActivity login", loginResult.toString());
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    // Application code
                    Log.v("LoginActivity", response.toString());
                    try {
                        String email = object.getString("email");
                        Log.v("LoginActivity", "obtained email: ", email);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            request.executeAsync();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.e("LoginActivity", "facebook login canceled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            Log.e("LoginActivity", "facebook login failed error");
        }
    };
    mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    mLoginMgr = LoginManager.getInstance();
    mLoginMgr.registerCallback(mCallbackManager, mFacebookCallback);
    mLoginMgr.logInWithReadPermissions(mActivity, mPermissions);
```

Using the `Debugger`, I am able to see that this line:
`mLoginMgr.logInWithReadPermissions(mActivity, mPermissions);`
gets executed, but none of the `callbacks` are ever triggered. I also have no errors in console, and the Device screen goes black and nothing happens.

I don't think it matters, but the code is executed in a wrapper class (outside `Activity`). I tried inside the `Activity`, but it made no difference.

Any suggestions?
Much appreciated.

Edit:

This is declared inside `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
          android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Comment: Have you configured AndroidManifest.xml per the [migration guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x)?

Comment: Yes, as per documentation. The `app_id` is provided programatically, because the app is localized.

Comment: That's really weird, maybe try their sample app and at least make sure your facebook app on dev website is correctly set up. I've encountered some issues while migrating, but not something like this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your code is in a fragment, do not use **mActivity** variable as Activity context.

To do:

1. Add a line:

   ```
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); in onActivityResult(, , , ) in fragment.
   ```
2. Call:

   ```
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(**this**, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
   ```

Use **this**, not use **this.getActivity()**

3. Sure, Done.

Comment: Indeed, the issue was that I forgot to add the call to `callbackManager.onActivityResult()`; unfortunatelly, I can't accept both answers.

Comment: 2. Call: LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(**this**, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends")); , Android Studio complaining "no method to resolve"

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem also.  Turns out I forgot to add the call to `callbackManager.onActivityResult()` in `Activity.onActivityResult()` as per the bottom of the [Register a Callback section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.4#callback_handling) of the login guide.

So in the Activity in which you're doing Facebook login, you should have something like:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallbackManager.onActivityResult(request, result, data);
}
```

Is this what you were missing?

Comment: This answer saved my time when working with Xamarin.Facebook SDK for Android. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
/** login manager */
    public void initializeLoginManager(){
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                    }
                });
    }

public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.button_login_login :
                firebaseloginEmail();
                break;

            case R.id.text_forget_password : break;//TODO: implement This with the layout

            case R.id.text_dont_account_login :
                startActivity(new Intent(this,SignupActivity.class));
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.button_facebook_login :
                Log.e("facebook login","You have clicked");
                LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this,Arrays.asList(EMAIL));
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: please explain how this answers the question, don't just post a wall of code